# Android screen orientation changed, textviews that are programmatically added are not saved

Tags: android, android-activity, view, android-orientation

Basically I have two activities. The main activity has a button that goes to the second activity which specifies the name of the textview (three textviews to be specific). After that, going back the the main activity, the specified name of the textview will be displayed on the first activity but the textviews are added programmatically and is added on to different tablerows based on its name. My problem is that when the screen orientation is changed from portrait to landscape, the textviews that are programatically added are not saved. How would I save those values? I've tried android:configChanges but it doesn't save anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override onSaveInstanceState method and put all values you want to save. Get them back in onRestoreIntanceState method.

UPDATED

Save needed values

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString(KEY, VALUE);
...
}
```

Restore values

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        String str = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY);
        //Set str to your text view
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you for answering my question. If you could kindly give me an example on how to do that? I'm confused on how to save it on the textview that is added programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, in the second activity you need to specify the text which will assigned to a few text views in the first aka main activity.

I would recommend the two ways:

1. Use `savedInstanceState`, `onSaveInstanceState()` to save and extract the strings of your text views you've set programmatically.
2. Apply `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to the main activity to prevent it from being recreated.

There are [the first way](https://gist.github.com/MaksimDmitriev/e6c4c365c389805c257d/d06ebadf6cb505ccfa906c19cc6ba2ce330ffae5) and [the second way](https://gist.github.com/MaksimDmitriev/e6c4c365c389805c257d) on Gist.
And you can also see the diff [here](https://gist.github.com/MaksimDmitriev/e6c4c365c389805c257d/revisions) (2 changed files with 4 additions and 17 deletions).

Answer (score 0):

Put the code that adds the textViews in a method and call it in onCreate and also in onConfigurationChanged

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    addTextViews();
}
```

Comment: Hello do you mean that I will put the added textviews on onActivityResult? Because the result of the name of the textviews will be based on the intent from the second activity.

Comment: No, but you should save the name in a variable and use it when adding the textViews

Answer (score 0):

android by default will recreate your UI upon configuration change(in your case, screen rotation change), now since your textviews/widgets are added in run time, they wont be recreated by android, as they are not available in XML layout which android will re inflate and add.

for your solution you do this, save the values your dynamically added views has by implementing `onSaveInstanceState`, use those view ID as key while storing the values(probably use row_id as views id).

now when configuration changes, based on saved values recreate your view and populate them with saved values, i guess this info might help you resolve this.

Comment: Hello thank you for answering my question. Should I include to put the ID programmatically also?

Comment: Yes, use SetID api for doing that !!

Comment: void initializeTextView() {
  mTextView = new TextView(this);
  mTextView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  mTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                mTextView.setId(100);
 }

Comment: @Override
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  outState.putString(100, "textViewString");
 }

Comment: Sorry am I on the right track? I have provided my code when I initialize my textview programmatically and the onSaveInstanceState method..